# How to put files into riscv linux?

Tags: linux, riscv, zynq

ri
1.We tried to install the rocket chip with risc-v linux on Zedboard, and we had successfully entered riscv linux. However, we couldn't put the files compiled by assembler(using the instruction : riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++) into riscv linux. Would someone please tell me how to put it in? (p.s we tried to mount the files into the file called root.bin,but it seems that risc-v linux doesn't use this file to boot.)
2. If we use the linux instrustion [make CONFIG=RoccExampleConfig] on our workshop, would it be RoCC there? If not, how to enable RoCC?

Answer (score 1):

The file boot.bin is read by the firmware executed by the Zynq ARM CPU on boot. It contains the boot loader and instructions to boot Linux on that CPU. It may also contain a bitstream for the programmable logic.

According to https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq/issues/22 you need to put your files into the RISC-V initramfs file until tether is working.

Comment: thanks,I already gave up ,using PK to execute code instead of putting it into riscv linux